# Is it possible to import CPython variables without PyPy module conflicts

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, pypy

I have a script that is using CPython and has pywin32 modules win32gui, and win32con. I have a variable that I want to import from this script into a different PyPy script to use its value.

It looks something like this:

```py
from functions import var1
```

however when I try to run this code I get the error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/folder/functions.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32gui, win32con
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32gui'
```

All I need is the value of the variable which is an integer, in any way possible. I think I could perhaps make a function that wraps the value of the variable and send it to the script that way, but I think that might be inefficient.

Is there someway, to avoid module conflicts like this when using different interpreters for different scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
try:
    import win32gui, win32con
except ImportError:
    win32gui = None
    wn32con = None
```

then later in your code, where you use these imports, check if they are None first.

Comment: This is an interesting way to fix it, the only problem is the module I am importing the variable from needs the imports to function correctly, and I am trying to import the value of the variable while it is running. The only thing I can think of is having the original script write the value to a text file and have the other one read it. But I don't know if that would work

Comment: Another option is to cause pywin32 to work on PyPy, see this issue https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1289, maybe you can help get it to work